# google test coverage for c++ in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, googletest

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10, Eclipse neon.3 and googletest for my C++ programming.
Is there any way that I can can make a coverage test with gtest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Eclipse plugin [Linux Tools - Gcov Support](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/gcov/).

> The Linux Tools Gcov plugin aims to bring the coverage capabilities of Gcov to Eclipse, in a manner that is easy to use for developers of any level of experience.

See also the [GCov Plug-in User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.gcov.docs%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FGCov%2FUser_Guide%2FUser-Guide.html&cp=26_0_0).

Comment: Thanks, i found also this:

http://www.cc.ntut.edu.tw/~wkchen/courses/gposd/gposd102_1/Coverage_gcov_Eclipse.pdf

perhaps this can also help someone.